# Converting Objective-C to Swift: Assigning to self

Tags: objective-c, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to translate an init method for UICollectionViewController from Obj-C to Swift. Here is the original code:

```
-(id)initWithCollectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)layout {
    if (self = [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout]) {
      [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]  forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_ID];
      [self.collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
override init(collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout!) {
        super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        self.collectionView?.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CELL_ID")
        self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

I'm having trouble converting the assignment to `self`. I've read the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_318 but to no avail. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When initializing an object in Swift it is guaranteed to be safe.

Therefore, there is no need to check it for nil values.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to assign to self in a Swift constructor. What you have above is fine.

However, `UICollectionViewCell.self` should just be `UICollectionViewCell`.